# Simple online text editor with a vertical split window

Tags: web-apps, text-editor

I am looking for a free, usable without registration, online web text editor that...

- supports a vertical split pane. I want be able to write different text on both vertical panes and thus being able to compare them visually.
- plain ASCII support is sufficient. No extra bells and whistles needed/wanted.
- no special features for search/replace required (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> from the browser is fine)

As a bonus but not necessary:

- Markdown formatting support
- Visual highlighting of text differences (diff tool) such as provided by for instance [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/)

Do you know of any web application that offers that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create your own pretty easily if you have a html 5 compatible browser. Just create an html file with the following markup.

```
<div style="width: 100%; display: table;">
    <div style="display: table-row">
        <div style="width: 300px; display: table-cell;" contenteditable>Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;" contenteditable>Lorem Ipsum</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The part that makes it editable is the attribute **contenteditable**. If the width of the columns is not what you want, you can change the width of the first column which is currently 300px.

You can see a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2bJmX/2/) of this on jsfiddle. Click on the text to edit.

If you want something fancier, you could check out [Aloha Editor](http://aloha-editor.org). Here is a [demo](http://aloha-editor.org/demos/960-fluid-demo/) of the editor being used with divs that you could control.

Also, there are lots of online diff tools, for example, [Diff Checker](http://www.diffchecker.com/), [Quick Diff](http://www.quickdiff.com/), [Diff Now](http://www.diffnow.com/), [Pretty Diff](http://prettydiff.com/), and [Text Compare](http://text-compare.com/).

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I particularly like Diff Checker, DiffNow and Text Compare because they are very simple and allow me to share and preserve the comparison for a certain time period.